# Javascript drag and drop multiple instances of the same object

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I want to develop a javascript drag and drop application just like the one you can see [here](http://www.compago.it/ajax/ID-48149.HeadA.Hack_54.html) , where you can pick and object and drag it to another area. But i want to do this with a twist. I want to be able do drag the same object multiple time, instead of moving the object from the book shelf to the basket, i want to drag one instance of the object to the book shelf and still have the object on the book shelf.

It's like buying multiple instances of the same object, each time i drag the object from the book shelf to the basket, i add another instance of the object to the basket.

Any ideas on how can i achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do the same thing as with regular drag and drop but instead of removing the dragged object, you clone it.

Implementing drag and drop is kind of tricky, a library like jQuery could really save you a lot of time and effort. [jQuery UI's draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) has a `helper: clone` option which leaves the dragged object in place, cloning it instead. Then when defining your drop area using [jQuery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) you can do whatever you want with the dropped element, like creating a new element representing the basket item, leaving the dragged item untouched. So if using jQuery is an option, that wouldn't be difficult to do at all.

**[UPDATE: HERE'S A QUICK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QGdCv/)**

HTML

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="productItem">product 1</div>
    <div class="productItem">product 2</div>
    <div class="productItem">product 3</div>
</div>

<div id="basket">
</div>​
```

JS

```
$(".productItem").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    handle: "productItem"
});

$("#basket").droppable({
    accept: ".productItem",
    drop: function(event, ui){
        $("<div></div>")
            .html(ui.draggable.text())
            .appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

​

Comment: Yes, using jQuery is not a problem, thanks for the information, i will check it.

Comment: @Cláudio Ribeiro I updated my answer with a quick demo fiddle.