# Drag and Drop in native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

I develop some kind of BPMN editor. 
[image]

Each time a drag and drop image from Toolbar to the canvas I expect to see a new groupObject. But that works only with the first element (rectangle), and only for the first time. Since one element had been added, onDrop event didn't work and I got my img.png in a new window instead of groupObject.

**HTML-block**

```
    <div id="toolbarPanel">
        <h4>Toolbar</h4>

        <img class="rectangle" src="/Content/img/rectangle.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragElement(event)" alt="rectangle"/>
        <img class="circle" src="/Content/img/circle.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragElement(event)" alt="circle"/>
    </div>
    <canvas id="flowCanvas" width="800" height="800" ondrop="dropElement(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></canvas>
    <div id="props">
        <h4>Properties</h4>
    </div>
```

**Script-block**

```
    var dragElementType;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('flowCanvas');

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function dragElement(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("image/png", ev.target.className);
        dragElementType = ev.target.className;
    }

    function dropElement(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, ev);

        drawFlowObj(dragElementType, mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    }

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }
```

So the question is: how to make DnD work for all shapes each time I drag it, not only the first time. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462451/javascript-drag-and-drop-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object), but I want to avoid jQuery, if it's possible. Maybe someone can just explain the steps I need to do.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? The code that you have there is a mixture of things that need to come before your html and things that need to come after (`dragElement` and `allowDrop` need to come before so they're not undefined, while `getElementById('flowCanvas')` needs to come after). I dumped your code into a jsfiddle and it blew up. I'd assume maybe it works once, errors, then because of that ceases to function.

Comment: This code is a part of MVC project, and I browse it in a `RenderScript section` on the _Layout master page. So in my project everything works fine, no errors in console.

Comment: Ok interesting, it must be refactoring it somehow then.

Comment: I'll try to make a correct jsfiddle and update my question.